# How to group by? Django Rest Framework

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I am developing an API Rest based on Django, I have two models:

- Album
- Track

I am trying to get the right format on this JSON (this is what I am getting now):

```
[
    {
        "album": "album-123kj23mmmasd",
        "track": {
            "id": 6,
            "uuid": "2c553219-9833-43e4-9fd1-44f536",
            "name": "song name 1",
        },
        "duration": 2
    },
    {
        "album": "album-123kj23mmmasd",
        "track": {
            "id": 7,
            "uuid": "9e5ef1da-9833-43e4-9fd1-415547a",
            "name": "song name 5",
        },
        "duration": 4
    },
```

This is what I would like to reach, I would like to group by 'albums':

```
[
    {
        "album": "album-123kj23mmmasd",
        "tracks": [{
                "id": 6,
                "uuid": "2c553219-9833-43e4-9fd1-44f536",
                "name": "song name 1",
                "duration": 2
             },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "uuid": "9e5ef1da-9833-43e4-9fd1-415547a",
                "name": "song name 5",
                "duration": 4
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

**EDIT 1: I am using Foreign Key instead ManyToMany**

```
class Track(models.Model:
    name, creation_date, etc...
class Album(models.Model):
    track = models.Foreignkey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could serialize Album and include a field `tracks = YourTrackSerializer(many=True)` assuming you have either a ManyToManyField or a related_name called 'tracks'

Comment: I suggest you include also the definition of your models, view and serializer in the question.

Comment: I just added the models

Comment: Do you think BaseSerializer could be an option?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**
Due the model complexity, I decided to user BaseSerializer, which allows to create custom response.

Comment: what was your solution?

Comment: Hi @HarryMoreno finally I decided to use BaseSerializer and "code" the JSON construction on the serializer

Comment: can you share that solution